# Get operation in a structure in golang

Tags: go

Below is a simple program. But what I don't understand is that how is the Get operation working? I have not defined any Get Method, but form.Get is working. How?

Sincerely,
Sudarsan.D

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
       "net/url"
)

type errors map[string]string;

type Form struct {
    url.Values;
    Errors errors;
}

func  New (data url.Values) (*Form) {
    return &Form {
        data,
        errors(map[string]string{}),
    };
}


func main () {
   k1 := url.Values{};
   k1.Set("arvind","superstar");
   k1.Set("title","Arvind");
   form := New(k1);
   fmt.Println("The title is", form.Get("arvind"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in the `Form` struct you did not provide a name explicitly for the `url.Values` field, that field is said to be **embedded**. An embedded field's name is automatically set to the type's unqualified name, i.e. in this case the `url.Values` field's name becomes `Values`. Also, an embedded field type's methods (if it has any) and fields (if it is a struct with any) are said to be **promoted** to the embedding struct. A promoted method or field *can* be accessed directly through the embedding struct, without having to specify the embedded field's name. i.e. instead of `form.Values.Get("arvind")` you can do `form.Get("arving")`.

Keep in mind that the two expressions `form.Values.Get("arvind")` and `form.Get("arving")` are semantically equivalent. In both cases you are calling the method `Get` on the `form.Values` field even though in the second expression the field's name is omitted.

---

From the language spec on [Struct types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which
> has a name and a type. **Field names may be specified explicitly
> (IdentifierList) or implicitly (EmbeddedField)**.
>
> ...
>
> **A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an
> embedded field.** An embedded field must be specified as a type name `T`
> or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not
> be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field name.**
>
> ...
>
> **A field or method `f` of an embedded field in a struct `x` is called
> promoted if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method
> `f`.**
>
> ...
>
> Given a struct type `S` and a defined type `T`, promoted methods are
> included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - **If `S` contains an embedded field `T`, the method sets of `S` and `*S` both
>   include promoted methods with receiver `T`. The method set of `*S` also
>   includes promoted methods with receiver `*T`.**
> - **If `S` contains an embedded
>   field `*T`, the method sets of `S` and `*S` both include promoted methods
>   with receiver `T` or `*T`.**